# Stopping a long-running asynchronous computation

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm writing a program that will perform a long-running computation, gradually improving a solution. On top of that, there's a simple UI that basically allows the user to stop the computation (letting the worker finish a step it's working on) and shows the best solution.
Here's a simplified version of what I have, I'm using async/await for the first time. Is there anything you would improve, or any other comments?

**Worker code**

```
public class SearchEngine
{
    //...
    public async Task<IProblemSolution> Search(CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            BestSolution = Problem.RandomSolution();
            while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                IProblemSolution s = Problem.RandomSolution(); // for simplification 
                if (s.ObjectiveValue() < BestSolution.ObjectiveValue())
                    BestSolution = s;
            }
        });
        return BestSolution;
    }
}
```

**UI**

```
    private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CancelTokenSrc != null)
            return;

        CancelTokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Engine = new SearchEngine(new SampleProblem());

        StopButton.IsEnabled = true;
        StartButton.IsEnabled = false;
        Task<IProblemSolution> t = Engine.Search(CancelTokenSrc);
        await t;

        ResultLabel.Content = t.Result.ObjectiveValue().ToString();
        StopButton.IsEnabled = false;
        StartButton.IsEnabled = true;
        CancelTokenSrc = null;
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CancelTokenSrc != null)
            CancelTokenSrc.Cancel();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Task-based Asynchronous Pattern ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx))

> ```
> public async Task<IProblemSolution> Search(CancellationTokenSource cts)
> ```

As I explain in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46004/23788), one would rightfully expect the signature of that method to read like this:

```
public async Task<IProblemSolution> SearchAsync(CancellationTokenSource cts)
```

The pattern for `async` methods is quite simple: use the `async` keyword, return `Task` or `Task<T>`, and put an "Async" suffix to the method's name.

---

I haven't written much `async` code (read: never wrote a line of C# that leverages features of .net 4.5), but from previous reviews of such code I think this:

```
    Task<IProblemSolution> t = Engine.Search(CancelTokenSrc);
    await t;

    ResultLabel.Content = t.Result.ObjectiveValue().ToString();
```

Could be written like this:

```
    var searchResult =  await Engine.SearchAsync(CancelTokenSrc);
    ResultLabel.Content = searchResult.ObjectiveValue().ToString();
    //...
```

My understanding is that `await` somehow deals with `Task.Result` and so the type of `searchResult` would be `IProblemSolution` - I might be wrong here though.

Other than that, I find you could give `var` some lovin', and change this:

```
IProblemSolution s = Problem.RandomSolution();
```

To this:

```
var s = Problem.RandomSolution();
```

Lastly, I might be biased because I use ReSharper and with that tool IntelliSense/auto-complete is much "smarter", but I don't like names like `cts` - I'd rather call it `cancelTokenSource` and then I can type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and poof I'm referring to a readable identifier with a pronounceable name.

Comment: “I don't think the Click handler for your StartButton is called asynchronously, you can drop the async keyword in that signature.” That's not how `async` works. It's required if you use `await`, which this method does. And since it's an event handler, `async void` is the right signature.

Comment: But you're right about the part of using `await` instead of `Result`.

Comment: @svick right, [just found out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14455293/1188513) - I'll edit to correct. Thanks!