# Async and error-handling

Tags: c#, error-handling, async-await

I need to delete a file when an error occurs during loading it. It is not allowed to perform async operations in a catch block.

This has lead me to writing the following code:

```
    public async Task LoadFromStorageFile(string fileName)
    {
        StorageFile file = null;            
        Exception ex1 = null;

        try
        {
            var folder = await ApplicationHelper.GetApplicationSaveFolder();
            file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            // ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex1 = ex;
        }

        try
        {
            if (ex1 != null && file != null)
            {
                await file.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             //...
        }
        finally
        {
            if(ex1 != null)
                throw ex1;
        }
    }
```

Is there a nicer way of doing this? The rethrown exception especially bugs me.

Comment: “It is not allowed to perform async operations in a catch block.” Not yet, it's probably going to be allowed in C# 6.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *I need to delete a file when an error occurs during loading it.*

In other words:

**Happy path**:

- Load a file
- Move on

**Unhappy path**:

- Load a file, exception is thrown
- Delete the file
- Move on

**Exceptional path**:

- Load a file, exception is thrown
- Delete the file, exception is thrown
- Handle exception, move on

---

From these points, it appears we'd need a task that loads a file. If that task fails, we need to try to handle the unhappy path gracefully.

I haven't written async code with async/await, but I'd probably get away with this using a `Task` that loads the file, and then decide whether I'd `.ContinueWith` another `Task` that deletes the file, and then decide how to handle the exceptional path where that other task would have failed.

---

#### Signature

> ```
> public async Task LoadFromStorageFile(string fileName)
> ```

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15951824/1188513) refers to an authoritative source for async method naming conventions:

> The [*Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) dictates that methods should
>   always return a `Task<T>` (or `Task`) and be named with an Async suffix;
>   this is separate from the use of `async`. Certainly, `Task<bool> Connect()` 
>   (or `async Task<bool> Connect()`) will compile and run just
>   fine, but you won't be following the TAP naming convention.

The signature for `Task LoadFromStorageFile(string)` would follow the naming convention for the pattern, by appending "Async" to the method's name:

```
public async Task LoadFromStorageFileAsync(string fileName)
```

---

#### Async/Await Exception Handling

As I've found in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5383408/1188513), an exception thrown in an async method will bubble up to the caller, so whoever called `await LoadFromStorageFileAsync("somefile.txt");` can know whether to move on, or to handle the unhappy path.

> *It is not allowed to perform async operations in a catch block.*

Indeed. There's [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868123/await-in-catch-block), with [a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8869589/1188513) from one of our top reviewers here on CR, that shows how that limitation can be circumvented. In a nutshell:

> ```
> bool loadSucceeded;
> try
> {
>     var folder = await ApplicationHelper.GetApplicationSaveFolder();
>     file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
>     // ...
>
>     loadSucceeded = true;
> }
> catch
> {
>     loadSucceeded = false;
> }
> ```

---

`LoadFromStorageFileAsync` can then look like this:

```
public async Task LoadFromStorageFileAsync(string fileName)
{
    bool loadSucceeded;
    StorageFile file;

    try
    {
        // happy path
        var folder = await ApplicationHelper.GetApplicationSaveFolder();
        file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        // ...

        loadSucceeded = true;
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        // log exception

        loadSucceeded = false;
    }

    if (!loadSucceeded && file != null) 
    {
        try
        {
            // unhappy path
            await file.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
            deleteSucceeded = true;
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            // exceptional path
            // log exception
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't rethrow whatever exception caused `loadSucceeded` to be `false` - rethrowing that exception in the *unhappy path* makes no sense, as was said before, that `finally` block is not needed. Instead, you could `catch(Exception exception)` (or anything more specific) in the *happy path*'s `catch` block, and write a trace, a debug, or a warning log entry with the exception and its stack trace. At that point, it's taken care of, there's no need to re-throw it.

Answer (score 3):

Couple random observations:

This initialization is redundant:

```
    StorageFile file = null;            
    Exception ex1 = null;
```

Because all reference type default to `null`, this is rigorously equivalent:

```
    StorageFile file;            
    Exception ex1;
```

Your method is doing 2 things, it should be broken down into 2 methods.

`throw ex1` is kissing your stack trace goodbye, and throwing an exception in a `finally` block is rather... unusual. Why keep a reference to an exception that you're going to be throwing anyway? If the first `try` block throws, that's it, I'd be expecting `file` to be `null` and to not be entering the condition in the second `try` block.

```
    catch (Exception)
    {
         //...
    }
```

This no-op `catch` block is swallowing any & all exceptions - don't do that. If you can't handle an exception in a meaningful and useful way, then *let it blow up*! Let the caller do something about an unhandled exception, don't just *pretend* everything went fine! The minimum you could do is something like this (assuming you're using a logging framework):

```
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
         _logger.WarnException(exception);
    }
```

Comment: I'll contest `Type value = null;` is equivalent to `Type value;` since @thumbmunkeys is using ex1 in a finally block, it MUST be set to something before ever getting there.  Try it.

Comment: thanks for your remarks. I know not to swallow exceptions, I left non relevant parts out of my code. You cannot access an uninitialized local variable in c#, so `file` and `ex1` have to be initialized. `folder` is in this context indeed not neccessary (in my real code it isn't). I agree the finalizer block is superflous. Could you give a suggestion how to divide the code, so that the stacktrace is not lost?

Comment: @Tory good point